# How I can save edit box values on a single button click

Tags: repeater, xpages

I have an EditBox control in a repeat control and its repeat limit is 30. How I can save all edit box values on a single button click.

Comment: How are the edit boxes bound to the data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Edit box is bound to data using simple data binding and Repeater control is bound to a view.

Answer (score 0):

Since your fields are bound to data sources....
`save()` is a global function that saves all bound field regardless to the data source.